# Rewrite inline query into stored procedure

Tags: mysql

```
   SELECT cpproductid
      FROM cp_detections
     WHERE   cpproductId IN
                  (SELECT cpproductId
                     FROM cp_detections
                    WHERE    (detectionId = 103 AND numdetections = 16)
                          OR (detectionId = 8 AND numdetections = 1)
                          OR (detectionId = 2 AND numdetections = 1)
                          OR (detectionId = 94 AND numdetections = 1)
                          OR (detectionId = 23 AND numdetections = 1)
                          OR (detectionId = 15 AND numdetections = 1))
           AND cpproductId NOT IN
                  (SELECT cpproductId
                     FROM cp_detections
                    WHERE     (detectionId != 103 AND numdetections != 0)
                          AND (detectionId != 8 AND numdetections != 0)
                          AND (detectionId != 2 AND numdetections != 0)
                          AND (detectionId != 94 AND numdetections != 0)
                          AND (detectionId != 23 AND numdetections != 0)
                          AND (detectionId != 15 AND numdetections != 0))
    GROUP BY cpproductId
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 6
```

The table is having three columns, cpproductId ,detectionId, numdetections
I have the above query where the values detectionId and numdetections have to be passed as an input parameters, right now the query is written as an inline query in source code, I want to write this into the stored procedure. The first subquery I have written by using the `find_in_set` like,

```
SELECT cpproductId,detectionId,numdetections 
FROM cp_detections 
WHERE find_in_set(Concat(detectionId, '|', numdetections),"103|16,8|1,10|1");
```

But I am not able to write the second subquery correctly to get the same output.

Comment: De Morgan's Laws should be helpful in figuring this out.

Comment: Maybe not. Does that query actually return anything?